# can not resolve property tag with job parameter

Tags: properties, spring-batch

I am trying to concatenate the job parameter,  #{jobParameters['arg1']} with myfeed.query to dynamically pick the right query from the properties file. But it's not getting resolved.

below is the exception log
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Executing query; bad SQL grammar [${myfeed.queryZONE1}]

below is the code snippet in the xml file.

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>${myfeed.query#{jobParameters['arg1']}}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.sgcib.loa.matrix.mapper.MyFeedRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you will need to declare explicit properties for your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` :

```
<bean id="propertiesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:xxxxxxx.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then using Spring Expression Language (spEL), you can get the right property with :

```
<property name="sql" value="#{properties.getProperty('myfeed.query' + jobParameters['arg1'])}" /></property>
```

Note that this solution maintains compatibility with `${...}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does not work, tested solution is [One ItemReader, 2 SQL Query, jdbcTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277664/one-itemreader-2-sql-query-jdbctemplate)

http://incomplete-code.blogspot.in/2013/06/dynamically-switch-sql-statements-in.html